# Magento 2 Error: technical problem with the server created an error on logo upload Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, theme, upload, logo, magento2.3.0

On Magento 2.3.0 version when you try to upload logo for theme from admin side it will gives error as below:

> **"technical problem with the server created an error."**

Is there something wrong with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mangento 2.3.0 version when you try to upload logo for theme and if you got the error as

> technical problem with the server created an error

then you need to change in below file :

> app/code/Magento/Theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

replace below code :

```
field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="imageUploader">
```

with

```
field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="fileUploader">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug in Magento 2.3 latest version, but you can fix this issue by change below code.

Go to this file: `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml` and please remove "**fileUploader**" and add "**imageUploader**".

```
 <collapsible>true</collapsible>
                <label translate="true">HTML Head</label>
            </settings>
            <!-- Remove this code -->
            <!-- <field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="fileUploader">-->

            <!-- Add this code -->
            <field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="imageUploader">
                <settings>
                    <notice translate="true">Not all browsers support all these formats!</notice>
                    <label translate="true">Favicon Icon</label>

                <collapsible>true</collapsible>
                <label translate="true">Header</label>
            </settings>
            <!-- Remove this code -->
            <!-- <field name="header_logo_src" formElement="fileUploader"> -->

            <!-- Add this code -->
            <field name="header_logo_src" formElement="imageUploader">
                <settings>
                    <label translate="true">Logo Image</label>
                    <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
```

This issue will be fixed in new Magento version, You can see PR here https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/20092